# how to convert Icollection item to an F# list/seq/array

Tags: c#, f#

How to:

`ICollection -> f# list`

Comment: You just asked the same question an hour ago. Why do you expect a different answer by asking it again? Why don't you simply provide *more* information in the original question?

Comment: Where are you having problems? What are `nd` and `el`? What would you like to happen?

Comment: if you just go with `nd.Values` (well if it's an dictionary) then you'll have a `seq` already - no need to get an `Enumerator` at all (you really don't want this ever)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Vote to close?

Comment: @MarkSeemann  Done. I don't easily vote to close due to that gold C# badge - it means the question is closed immediatelly. In this case though I really see no difference between the questions. In fact, the original question offers *more* information

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Agreed, I feel the same way about having the C# gold badge. It's too easy to close questions, but I agree that in this case, it was the right thing to do.

Comment: i need an f# list, not an ICollection.  My question is not answered. This is obvious.